# How to test the "open-in-app" feature for the branch link created using Branch.io in development build?

Tags: ios, branch.io

I have an application which is already in App Store.I have to check the branch linking feature I added using Branch.io in development build.That is, when a user shares something on social networks, clicking on the shared post should open the application installed. So how do I check this functionality in development build?

Answer (score 2):

Alex from Branch.io here: Branch doesn't know (or care) *how* the application is installed onto your device. Installing directly from Xcode and using a beta distribution system (TestFlight, Hockey, Fabric, etc.) are treated exactly the same way as going through the App Store.

Here is a flow you can use to test this:

1. Install a build of your app that includes the Branch SDK
2. Generate a link and post it somewhere like iOS Notes
3. Uninstall your app
4. Open the link and let it redirect all the way through to the App Store page
5. Close the App Store
6. Install a build of your app locally (using either Xcode or TestFlight/Fabric/etc.)
7. Open your app
8. The link data will be returned to you, exactly the same way it would be when your app is installed from the App Store by a user.

Comment: 1.I have taken a build from Xcode with distribution certificate, installed it and shared a post on facebook.
2.Clicked on the link and redirected to my web page as I set on branch dashboard,from there redirected to App store application.
3.Uninstalled the app and reinstalled.
4.Clicked on the link shared to open the application, but it doesn't help.

I have used [getTestInstance] and have live and test keys in info.plist.

Please help.

Comment: Facebook is actually not a good place to test, because it blocks opening third-party apps (I edited the answer to reflect this). Try with the iOS Notes app instead. If you're using `getTestInstance()`, make sure the link you use to test was also generated using your test key, otherwise there will be a mismatch.

Comment: I was able to open the dev application with the link shared on email.But for facebook and twitter it redirects to appstore.And when I opened my application manually,it redirects to the page I needs to open while a user clikcs the link.I don't get why these social medias doesn't automatically open my application when clicked on the shared post.